# Is it possible to use the "extra" attribute associated to an apiserver request to make authorisation decisions with RBAC?

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, authorization, rbac

When a client authenticates to the apiserver, a number of [attributes are associated with the request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#authentication-strategies). These attributes include an "extra" attribute which is just a map of strings to lists of strings.

Authorisation plugins can review these attributes to make authorisation decisions. Does the RBAC authorisation plugin support reviewing these "extra" attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief description of extra attributes from [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/apiserver/blob/master/pkg/authentication/user/user.go#L31) tells that:

```
    // GetExtra can contain any additional information that the authenticator
    // thought was interesting.  One example would be scopes on a token.
    // Keys in this map should be namespaced to the authenticator or
    // authenticator/authorizer pair making use of them.
    // For instance: "example.org/foo" instead of "foo"
    // This is a map[string][]string because it needs to be serializeable into
    // a SubjectAccessReviewSpec.authorization.k8s.io for proper authorization
    // delegation flows
    // In order to faithfully round-trip through an impersonation flow, these keys
    // MUST be lowercase.
    GetExtra() map[string][]string
}

func (i *DefaultInfo) GetExtra() map[string][]string {
    return i.Extra
}
```

After reading the code I haven't found any reference to extra attributes.
It looks like extra attributes are not used in RBAC plugin at the moment, but can be used in [Webhook authorization mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/webhook/).

Comment: That's a shame, but expected as I have not seen any reference to them in the authorisation APIs - thanks for the source